# How do I make libusb work as non-root?

Tags: usb, permissions

I'm making a custom USB HID device, and a desktop app to go with it, using HIDAPI on Lubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.  We'll call it `myapp` for now.

Apparently, if I do `$ ./myapp`, `libusb_open()` fails with `LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS`.  <sub>(shown in my debugger as `-3`; it took a while to figure that out because the enum doesn't seem to be documented very well)</sub>
But if I do `$ sudo ./myapp`, it succeeds.
I really don't want `myapp` to have root permissions, so how can I talk to my USB device without them?

---

I was hoping for an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/325416/321777), but it seems to have been abandoned at exactly this point.  It says something about user permissions, but I can't seem to find that on my system.  I thought I might find a group called `usb` or `libusb` that I could add myself to, but no such luck.

---

[This question on a different SE site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44308/understanding-udev-rules-and-permissions-in-libusb) has an answer that uses some austere text files to change the permissions either globally (probably a bad idea) or for a specific device, but:

1. It's not the "muggle's tweak" that I was looking for.
2. Most of those files have a warning against modifying directly because they're auto-generated.  So how can I be sure that a random package update isn't going to wipe out my changes and thus break `myapp`?
3. It doesn't seem to do anything anyway.  I followed those instructions and rebooted, and `myapp` with user permissions still can't talk to USB.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44308/understanding-udev-rules-and-permissions-in-libusb

Comment: @Rinzwind I finally got some time during Thanksgiving gatherings to test that.  It does absolutely nothing on my system.  See edit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's still not the "muggle's tweak" that I'm really looking for, but at least this works:

Apparently there are two directories for udev (I have no idea why):

- `/etc/udev/rules.d`
- `/lib/udev/rules.d`

I'd been messing with the `/lib` one and getting nowhere.  I found the `/etc` one [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/15570), and it does work:

---

Put `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="VID", ATTRS{idProduct}=="PID", MODE="0666"`

- `VID` is the [USB-IF-assigned Vendor ID](http://www.usb.org/developers/vendor/) of the device in question *
- `PID` is the Vendor-assigned Product ID of the device in question *
- `0666` gives universal read/write access to whatever matches this line

  * <sub>`$ lsusb` to see all attached USB devices and their ID's.</sub>

In `/etc/udev/rules.d/xx-my-rule.rules` (may need root/sudo permissions)

- `xx` is any number > 50 (the defaults are in 50, and higher numbers take priority)
- `my-rule` is whatever you want to call it
- must end in `.rules`

Then `udevadm control --reload-rules` (may also need root/sudo permissions), and it should "just work" for that specific VID/PID pair.

---

Another option, to tighten the permissions a little bit more, is to use `TAG+="uaccess"` in place of `MODE="0666"`.  This limits access to the currently-logged-in (physical) user instead of all users.  Thanks @Lekensteyn!

Comment: As an alternative to the overly permissive `MODE="0666"`, consider using `TAG+="uaccess"` as used [here](https://github.com/pwr/Solaar/blob/master/rules.d/42-logitech-unify-permissions.rules#L44). It does not allow any local user to access the USB device, just the person who is logged in (physically). There is no need for `udevadm control --reload-rules`, it is read automatically. You just have to remove/reinsert the USB device after creating/changing that file.

Comment: That works too.  Changed the file, ran the possibly unnecessary update command, rebooted (rather do all that than get frustrated for hours because I didn't *tell* it to update; some things do need that), and it still works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else struggling with this - i needed to add **GROUP="plugdev"** to my udev rule under Ubuntu 18.04 to make it work.

so for my BTD-400 adapter the file **/etc/udev/rules.d/51-usb-device.rules** reads:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0a5c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="21e8", GROUP="plugdev", TAG+="uaccess"
```

Comment: I simply added the user to the `plugdev` group and it worked. I tried setting the group in the udev rule to one assigned to the user, but that failed. The udev rule may be unnecessary.

Comment: I just struggled with this to get Respeaker 'tuning.py' to work without sudo.  I had to perform the procedure in the accepted answer (change udev rules), then I had to add myself to plugdev group (sudo usermod -a -G plugdev paul).  After adding, plugdev does not show up in groups - need to reboot.  BOTH plugdev membership AND udev rule modifications were necessary.